# Xcode error: redefinition of enumerator 'MJPopupViewAnimation'

Tags: iphone, xcode, include

I'm trying to integrate to MJPopupViewAnimation so some of my pages in my app. But it seems like you can't define the functions in more than 1 file. The error I'm getting is:

redefinition of enumerator 'MJPopupViewAnimationFade'
redefinition of enumerator 'MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomTop'
redefinition of enumerator 'MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom'

And so on...

Can someone explain why I can't use it in more than 1 page?

/David

Comment: It sounds like you are just copy-pasting the code into your view controllers. It would help if you posted an example of exactly how you are trying to make this work...

Comment: Yes, I'm copy-pasting the same code in all of my view controllers. Is that the problem? @TheNextman

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MJPopupViewAnimation, but copy-pasting the code into your app in multiple places is not the best thing to do (you can probably make it work, but it's not ideal).

As per the instructions on [GitHub](https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController), you should:

1. Add the MJPopupViewController source files to your project
2. In the files where you wish to use the animation, import the category:

`#import "UIViewController+MJPopupViewController.h"`

Then you can go ahead and use the animations:

```
[self presentPopupViewController:detailViewController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
[self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
```

Comment: But then I get this error: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x862bb20

Comment: @DavidJohnsson You need to post some code, showing exactly what you are doing